# Redirecting to another window on close

Tags: java, javafx, stage

I have user window which I'm invoking after successful login. User stage is invoked by following code in LoginController class.

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        if (loginModel.isLoggedIn(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassField.getText())) {
            lblDBStatus.setText("Username and password are correct");

            String fxmlFile = "/fxml/User.fxml";
            LOG.debug("Loading FXML for User view from: {}", fxmlFile);

            LOG.info("Hiding login page");
            ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();


            Stage stage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile).openStream());
            UserController userController = (UserController) loader.getController();
            userController.getUserName(txtLogin.getText());

            LOG.info("Showing User page");
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/user-controller.css");

            stage.setTitle("WindOptimizer");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();


        } else {
            lblDBStatus.setText("Username and password are incorrect");

        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And now I have an another event handler that is redirecting me from UserController and it's creating Turbines window.

```
public void openTurbinesTab(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        String fxmlFile = "/fxml/WindTurbines.fxml";
        LOG.debug("Loading FXML for Turbines view from: {}", fxmlFile);

        LOG.info("Hiding user page");
        ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();


        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile).openStream());
        TurbinesController turbinesController = (TurbinesController) loader.getController();
        turbinesController.getStationName(stationCB.getValue().toString());

        LOG.info("Showing Turbines page");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/turbines-controller.css");

        stage.setTitle("WindOptimizer");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent event1) -> {


        });

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

After performing some actions in turbines window I would like to save this data (just like getUserName or getStationName) and after closing Turbines tab redirect back to user window. As You can see I'm pretty sure I should use `stage.setOnCloseRequest((WindowEvent event1)`, but unfortunately I have no idea what should provide in this method to successfully invoke back user window.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can call `Window.requestFocus()` (or `Stage.toFront()`?) inside the `onCloseRequest` handler. You'll need a reference to the other `Window` to do this.

Comment: What do You mean by reference to other window? Flow of program should look like this: open user window -> click button to redirect to turbines window -> close user window and open turbines window -> click exit button on turbines window -> hide turbines window and show user window again

Comment: I still didn't find any solution. Maybe it would be easier to create something on shape of back button or to focus on window that has been invoked and not allowing user to perform any action on other window (something similar to save file in text editors - u can't perform any action without previously saving or discarding changes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I managed to solve my problem:
I created static stage object in userController:

```
public static Stage userStage;
```

And changed login method which was invoking User Window as follows:

```
public void login(ActionEvent event) {
    try {
        if (loginModel.isLoggedIn(txtLogin.getText(), txtPassField.getText())) {
            lblDBStatus.setText("Username and password are correct");

            String fxmlFile = "/fxml/User.fxml";
            LOG.debug("Loading FXML for User view from: {}", fxmlFile);

            LOG.info("Hiding login page");
            ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow().hide();


            userStage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            Pane rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile).openStream());
            UserController userController = (UserController) loader.getController();
            userController.getUserName(txtLogin.getText());

            LOG.info("Showing User page");
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
            scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/user-controller.css");

            userStage.setTitle("WindOptimizer");
            userStage.setScene(scene);
            userStage.show();


        } else {
            lblDBStatus.setText("Username and password are incorrect");

        }
    } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then in userController i onvoked openTurbines tab and set focus on it:

```
public void openTurbinesTab(ActionEvent event) {

    try {
        String fxmlFile = "/fxml/WindTurbines.fxml";
        LOG.debug("Loading FXML for Turbines view from: {}", fxmlFile);

        LOG.info("Hiding user page");

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane rootNode = loader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile).openStream());

        TurbinesController turbinesController = (TurbinesController) loader.getController();
        turbinesController.getStationName(stationCB.getValue().toString());

        LOG.info("Showing Turbines page");
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/turbines-controller.css");

        stage.setTitle("WindOptimizer");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initOwner(LoginController.userStage);
        stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stage.showAndWait();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**And it`s working!**